# What are the factors effecting rate of adsorption?

Tags: physical-chemistry

It is well known that chromatography is based on the principle that different substances (mobile phase) get adsorbed at different rates/amount to the stationary phase. However, I can't don't get the mental picture of why substances get adsorbed faster and some slower. So, are there any physics explanation for the above?

I am looking something along the lines of how we can imagine temperature as how fast the  average gas molecules move in kinetic gas theory.